# how to pass a value to jquery if one or more checkbox in the first column of that row is selected?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

it is,

1. I need to make all check boxes enabled in first column of a table if the header check box is selected.
2. I need to pass the one or more than one or all selected check box's row id to jQuery function

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sick jQuery solution for your problem: http://briancray.com/posts/check-all-jquery-javascript

When you iterate down each tr in your table, do something like this:

```
// assume you have an array like:
$array = array(
     '0' => array(
            'name' => 'bob',
            'pet' => 'dog'
     ),
     '1' => array(
            'name' => 'josh',
            'pet' => 'cat'
     ), 
 );
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) { ?>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="rows[<?=$i?>]" /><td><?=$array[$i]['name']?></td><td><?=$array[$i]['pet'];?></td>
<? } ?>
```

Once you post that, you'll get an array in your post with the index of rows, which you can iterate through further.

If you want some more sample code I'll be glad to whip some up. This should help you get started though. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
But i have already designed an html table which come from an ajax function, in that first column contains check boxes and if i click single check box or more than one or all check box in first column, and if i click a button it needs to pass the id(refers to value in database) to jquery function. and from that function i need to insert or update it to database.

Answer (score 0):

use this type structure for html

```
<fieldset>
        <!-- these will be affected by check all -->
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> Check all</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <!-- these won't be affected by check all; different field set -->
        <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    </fieldset>
```

Here each fieldset all checkbox can checked using this jquery code, also getting all ids of checked checkbox

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
      var x =  $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('id');

    });
});
```